# Is there a way to have a QCamera stream on two different QVideoWidgets?

Tags: qt, qtmultimedia

I need to replicate the stream of a QCamera on two different QVideoWidgets (at the same time).
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, only a single display output can be attached to a media object at one time if you use the built-in api. You'll have to use a a `QCameraImageCapture` to explicitly capture `QVideoFrame`s from the camera. You can then display them on any widget, e.g. a `QLabel` by creating an pixmap that wraps the video data.

Comment: but is that as efficient as attaching the display output to the media object?  I mean, doesn't extracting the `QVideoFrames` and setting them in a `QLabel` after creating the `QPixmap` cost too much compared to the built in approach??

Comment: The built-in approach doesn't do what you need. If you're asking if there's another way of doing it other than patching QtMultimedia: I don't know of it.